# How to get value 2 Calc Function

Tags: javascript, function, calc

How i can make Javascript Function like that :

`findC("2 / c = 3")`

herei need to get c value using js function !

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible code for that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.